# Where does Yarn add global binaries on Windows?

Tags: tsc, yarnpkg

I'm on Windows 7, and I tried to install `typescript` with `yarn`:

```
yarn global add typescript

success Installed typescript@2.0.6 with binaries:
  - tsc
  - tsserver
Done in 11.59s.
```

After successful installation, I type `tsc` in the command line, only to find that the command is not available.

```
yarn tsc
yarn tsc v0.16.1
error Command "tsc" not found.
```

Get config:

```
yarn config get prefix
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin
```

I checked this path: there's no `tsc` or `tsserver` exectuables. Where is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yarn global installs to current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330759/yarn-global-installs-to-current-directory)

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1226

Comment: Were you running `tsc` or `yarn tsc`? I would have expected you would run the former, not the latter.

Comment: @JunleLi Thanks. Glad to hear that this is fixed by the official yarn team. It seems that yarn won't play well with nodist on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Actually, I tried both. Maybe Linux/Mac would saved me a lot of trouble. But I am just learn programming as a hobby, could not left Windows for daily office use.

Comment: On Windows, it is `%LocalAppData%\Yarn\bin`

Answer (score 24):

### Answering the actual question and using the default directory, rather than changing it:

Yarn installs to `${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\yarn\bin`

You can see this with:

```
yarn global bin
```

For example, after installing gulp:

```
$ ls ${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\yarn\bin


    Directory: C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\yarn\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        13-Aug-18   4:11 PM            348 gulp
-a----        13-Aug-18   4:11 PM             57 gulp.cmd
```

To ensure it's in your path, add this to your `$profile` (assuming you have [PSCX](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) ):

```
Add-PathVariable ${env:LOCALAPPDATA}\yarn\bin
```

Answer (score -2):

Check it with

```
yarn config get prefix
```

It [works now](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/630#issuecomment-277837483):

```
mkdir ~/yarn-global
yarn config set prefix ~/yarn-global
```

Add `~/yarn-global` to your `PATH` env var.