# Yarn global installs to current directory

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I am trying to get React Native working on my Linux machine. In order to get the cli running I have run:

```
$ yarn global add react-native-cli
```

and see:

```
yarn global v0.16.1
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed react-native-cli@1.0.0 with binaries:
      - react-native
Done in 1.70s.
```

Everything installs just fine, but when I attempt to create a new React Native project, I get:

```
$ react-native init Test
react-native: command not found
```

Come to find out, `yarn` is installing the dependency into whatever the current directory is instead of installing it globally. Any help on this? I'm running Lubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Now it [works](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/630#issuecomment-277837483):

`yarn config set prefix /usr/local`

Check with

`yarn config get prefix`

Notice that only executables will be installed to this `prefix` location. Packages i.e. on Windows are installed in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules`.

On Windows I do:

```
mkdir ~/yarn-global
yarn config set prefix ~/yarn-global
```

#### Old

Global path [isn't configurable permanently](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/630) yet. We can only read the settings:

```
> yarn global bin
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

When I tried to install elm-upgrade, I got error in log `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\yarn-error.log`

```
Trace:
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\elm-upgrade.cmd'
      at Error (native)
```

But elm-upgrade was installed in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\.bin`.

Related:

- Location of global bin doesn't match the doc https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1194

Comment: On Windows, it would be preferable anyway to not install in `C:\Program Files\nodejs` I think? Permissions for one thing and global is a per user repository.

Comment: Yarn ignore this setting anyway

Comment: @rofrol.  Thanks.  Are your files installed in the config set prefix folder?  For me I only get the cmd files in the prefix folder, the actual node_modules are still installed in AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules

Comment: @dan same for me, execs in prefix folder, packages in AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules. Added this info to answer